# Multi Value option in Apache Nifi Processor

Tags: hadoop, apache-nifi

I was designing on my own custom processor. I added couple of simple property descriptor into it with simple non-empty validators. I was looking for a validator by which I can add multiple values into one property descriptor. Something like below.

[image]

My property descriptor will have multi value selection option.

Does anyone know how can I achieve it ?

Answer (score 2):

Multi-value selection for a single property descriptor is not supported.  Would be curious to better understand the use case.  Now, of course you can have many properties and even support dynamically generated (at runtime) properties.

Thanks
Joe

Comment: Hi Joe ..I wanted a way in which i can describe multiple values into property descriptor, I can manually define comma separated values but  there will be chances of typing mistake. So wanted to restrict user in order to avoid such situation. Since there a limited values , multi-value option gives better way .